# How can I make a file to disappear once if it is deleted in android SD card?

Tags: android, listview, file-browser, android-external-storage

```
/*Files will be clicked here*/
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, final int position, long id){
    filePosition=new File(path1.get(position));
    System.out.println("File position:"+filePosition);
    if(filePosition.isDirectory()){
    if(filePosition.canRead())
            getDirectories(path1.get(position)); 
else
        {
new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoSDcard.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.folder)
            .setTitle("["+filePosition.getName()+"]folder can't be read!")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }).show();

        }

    }
else {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.folder);
        alert.setTitle("Do you want to Delete this File from SD card ?"+" [ "+filePosition.getName()+" ] ");

                  //.setTitle("["+filePosition.getName()+"]")
         alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                /*Deleting a File*/

                deleteFile(); // here deleting a file


            }

            private void deleteFile() {

                  boolean deleted= filePosition.delete();
    }


        });
```

I am browsing the files and directories from SD card. So Iam displaying it by using listview. When I don't need a file on sd card so I could be able to delete a file.

My problem is, after I deleting a file it has deleted completely on SD card but it is visible on listview. I meant in emulator. After deleting a file from the list , it should be disappear.

For an example:- I am having song.mp4 file on sd card. Once I deleted this file "song.mp4" then it should not be displayed again in a listview.

How should I do this?

Comment: you have to update your listview using notifysetchanged.

Comment: No, It didnt change anything :-(@segi

Comment: what does it mean mydataobject?@Segi MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);

Comment: just use your adapter instend of mydataobject and position of your listview item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

`deleteFile()` method in onclick event..

or

call same activity using intent after that..

Try like this:

```
adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        adb.setTitle("Delete?");
        adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
        final int positionToRemove = position;
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }});
        adb.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to update your listdataitem, and call this function just after deleting a file from sdcard. It will referesh your listItem. You may call the same function for first time to setdata list.

ActivityClass.java

```
ListView listview;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
    refreshData();
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            //show your dialogbox here
            //and on click of dialog's delete button referesh listview adapter and set it in listview.
            .
            .
             AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
             alert.setIcon(R.drawable.folder);
             alert.setTitle("Do you want to Delete this File from SD card ?"+" [ "+filePosition.getName()+" ] ");

              //.setTitle("["+filePosition.getName()+"]")
             alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            /*Deleting a File*/

            deleteFile(); // here deleting a file
           refreshData();//refersh listItem


        }

        private void deleteFile() {

              boolean deleted= filePosition.delete();
}




        }
    });





}

public void refreshData(){


    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
     listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```